# Clockwise rotating line

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am given a pivot point (by the integer coordinates) and a line that goes through that point and makes an x degree with the horizontal. The line makes a 360 degrees clockwise rotation around the pivot point with  speed s= 0.001 degree per second. I am now given N points (with integer coordinates) and I have to sort these points in the order in which the line touches these points. How can i compute this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something equivalent to the following:

1. [Translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29) everything so that the pivot point is at the origin
2. Convert each point to [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates).
3. Subtract `x` from each point's angle component, modulo 360 degrees (2pi radians).
4. Sort the angle components in ascending order.

Answer (score -1):

Write the comparison function that takes two points and compare the angles they make with horizontal line.